# Выполнение GET запроса, переход по ссылки запрещен

Tags: button, javascript, request, get

Здравствуйте, я уже писал тему на счет кнопки с GET запросом, все работает спасибо.
Но одна проблема, если я пишу onclick="return false" кнопка не каких запросов не посылает...
Как решить данную проблему, то есть, посылается запрос, но переход заблокирован.

Comment: @Insider, чем синхронный запрос (в прошлый раз вы отказывались от аякса) будет отличаться от перехода по ссылке? Как вы себе представляете финальный кейс? Сейчас получается что-то вроде "сделать запрос, но заблокировать запрос".

Comment: у меня есть уже готовый javascript но к этой кнопки он не подходит....
так как я пока что плохо знаю javascript, я не смогу подключить уже готовый.
В данном случие у меня нажимается кнопка, и вылазиет окошко с ответом в json формате "ok"

Comment: @Insider, это как раз-таки больше похоже на ajax-запрос.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JEaQWvxU